# Bash scripting & array pushing

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm trying to make a script which will find a files, take their dirnames and then go there and do something. I have a problem with adding elements to array, who I want to be my dirnames container.

Code looks like this:

```
dirnames=()
while read -r line; do
        echo "Looking for dirname "$line
        dirname=$( dirname $(egrep -lir --include=pom.xml "<name>"$line"</name>" $application_dir))
        dirnames+=($dirname)
done < $modules_file

echo "Acquired dirnames"
echo $dirnames
```

And this is the answer:

```
Looking for dirname a
Looking for dirname b
Looking for dirname c
Acquired dirnames
/home/user/dev/workspace/a
```

I have only first dir in my "array". It looks like every another iteration is missing, and i know that these other dirnames are found because of i trying to swap lines.

I was reading a lot about arrays in bash, but everywhere this kind of approach works fine.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash syntax to expand the entire array is this:

```
echo ${dirnames[*]}
```

Or you can access individual elements.  e.g.

```
echo ${dirnames[1]}
```

Or loop over array:

```
for d in ${dirnames[*]}; do
    echo $d
done
```

Comment: Ohh crap - thanks for this, I saw somewhere that someone was listing whole array with just name of array. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way you are printing your ***dirnames*** array. ***${dirnames}*** will only print the first element. Try printing it like this:

```
echo ${dirnames[@]}
```